# Excel Formula for Column Data Change based on Date Value from different Column in same table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new here, any help would be greatly appreciated.  This might be easy but looking online I just cant figure this out.

I have a table with 3 columns.

The columns are "Date", "Flavor", and "in Stock".  I am tracking the stock status for flavors of ice cream by day.

[Table Image 1] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1CbJ.png)

I want to create a formula that flags when a flavor moves from a "yes" position yesterday to a "no" position of being in stock today.

I want to save the result in a new column D called "CHANGE". This column will only populate if the stock status changes day over day.

So the formula would be:

"IF date is today" and
"Flavor is Vanilla" and
"Stock Status is "N" and
"Date is yesterday" and
"Flavor is Vanilla" and
"Stock Status is YES" - return "Changed" in column D.

Else return ""

So the final result would look like this:

[Table Image Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjpCj.png)

Comment: From your picture it seems you are just flagging the stock status `N`. So, use `=IF(C2="N","CHANGED","")`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help with my question.  I feel like I did not do a good job of explaning.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a formula that will tell me if a Flavor moved into an out of stock position based on the date column from that same row in the table.  So for example - if vanilla is in stock on April 5th row and then not in stock on April 6th row -the column will alert that the stock status for the flavor vanilla changed to "n" on the row with date April 6 and was "yes" in the row for April 5th...does this question make sense?